# Excluding Posts from The Loop in Wordpress based on Title

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to filter out some custom posts from The Loop that I have for my custom taxonomy query.

I have the code in a taxonomy-{custom-taxonomy-slug}.php file. Basically, I want any post that ends with the character "W" to be excluded.

I'm trying to order these posts by title, but by default it is putting posts with the title ending in -W at the beginning. I want them at the end as the -W suffix is what we use to show that the post is not in our catalog. So I was going to do that by just putting another loop at the end with the opposite rule.

Anyway, here is what I am working with so far:

```
            if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

                <div id="blog-entries" class="clr <?php ks_blog_wrap_classes(); ?>">


            <?php   
                    while ( have_posts()) : the_post(); 

                        $title=substr(get_the_title(), -1, 1);
                        if ($title!=w) continue; 

                        get_template_part( 'content-design-category', get_post_format() ); ?>

                    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: I think that would be a better way to use a custom field to mark posts that are not in the catalog, then you can exclude them easily from the query

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if ($title == 'w') continue;` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
            if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<div id="blog-entries" class="clr <?php ks_blog_wrap_classes(); ?>">


        <?php   
                while ( have_posts()) : the_post(); 

                    $title=substr(get_the_title(), -1, 1);
                    if ($title =='1') continue;  

                    get_template_part( 'content-design-category', get_post_format() ); ?>

                <?php endwhile; ?>
```